# Error when checking input: expected dense_34_input to have shape (33,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I want to pridt my array on my trained model but i'm getting this error

```
Error when checking input: expected dense_34_input to have shape (33,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

My code to reproduce this issus is:

```
    def start(self):
        self.df = pd.read_csv('data_use.csv')
        self.all_Algorithm = self.df
        d = 0
        self.ResultArray = self.all_Algorithm.loc[1+d:11+d]
        self.reversed_df = self.ResultArray.iloc[::-1]
        print(self.reversed_df)
        model = load_model('trained_model.h5')
        model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

        self.Array = pd.DataFrame() 
        for i in range(1,12):
            print(i)
            g = i * 3 - 2
            self.Array.at[g,'RowForInput'] = self.reversed_df.loc[i,'weight']
            self.Array.at[g+1,'RowForInput'] = self.reversed_df.loc[i,'Size']
            self.Array.at[g+2,'RowForInput'] = self.reversed_df.loc[i,'Age']
        print(self.Array.shape)

        results = model.predict(self.Array)
        print('test loss, test acc:', results)
```

Can anybody help?

**Edit**

According to the comments I changed how I initialized the array but now I'm getting this following error:

```
 Error when checking input: expected dense_34_input to have shape (33,) but got array with shape (0,)
```

Comment: You don't give a traceback or otherwise indicate where the error occurs, though a good guess is `model.predict(self.Array)`.  If so, have you looked at `self.Array`?  What is it?  Looks like a DataFrame.  You print the `shape` but don't tell us!  Is that model ok with a dataframe input?  Or would it rather have a numpy array (or tensor object)?

Comment: That code is nearly useless to us.  We can't reproduce your problem.  It's based on a couple of files that we can't load (and probably don't want to, even if you provided links).

Comment: @hpaulj Basically the issue what i'm facing is that I nedd an Array with one row and 33 columes. At the moment I have 33 rows and 1 colume. Do you have an idea how to inverse that?

Comment: If it's just a matter of changing a (1,33) array to (33,1), then `transpose` will do the trick.  But that's not what the error is telling us.

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Why did you initialize `self.Array` with  an empty column `Email`? From your code, it doesn't seem that you need it. If so, you can do instead

```
self.Array = pd.DataFrame()
```

If you really need it somewhere else (although it doesn't make sense having `Email` with `dtype='float32'`), do

```
results = model.predict(self.Array.iloc[:,1:]
```

Comment: You're defenitly right. I just put Email there as an placehoder for the row. I followed youre instructions but now i face an other issue.